# dojo how to get portlet position object that have value(column,row,width,height) in GridContainer?

Tags: dojo

hi my server tries to store information about portlet. I would like to get information(column,row,width,height) about the location of the portlet. but I think I have. more difficult to me..
for example there are two single portlet in GridContainer. I want to get information about the portlet on the column,row and the value of the width, height.if i imported value one of two portlet in GridContainer, the value of the first portlet row: 0, column: 0, width: 50px, height: 50px, the value of the second portlet row: 0, column: 1, width: 50px , height: 50px.
ask for advice.

my code

```
var selectedForm=registry.byId('tabContainer').get('selectedChildWidget');
var grid=selectedForm.getChildren();->have portlets in GridContainer
 var oldcolumn=null;
           var row=1;
           for(var i =0; i<grid.length;i++)
               {
               for(var j=0;j<grid[i].length;j++){
                if (oldcolumn==null)
                    oldcolumn=grid[i].getChildren()[j].domNode.parentNode.cellIndex;
                console.log(' column:'+grid[i].getChildren()[j].domNode.parentNode.cellIndex);
                if(oldcolumn == nodelist[i].domNode.parentNode.cellIndex)
                    console.log('column:'+grid[i].getChildren()[j].domNode.parentNode.cellIndex+'row:'+(++row));
                else
                    {
                    row=1;
                    oldcolumn=grid[i].getChildren()[j].domNode.parentNode.cellIndex;
                    console.log(' column:'+grid[i].getChildren()[j].domNode.parentNode.cellIndex'row:'+(++row));
                    }

               }
               }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Column

If I read the documentation about the `dojox/layout/GridContainer`, it states the following:

> By requiring the GridContainer, two new attributes are mixed into the
>   dijit/_WidgetBase class:
>
> - column: Holds the current column a widget is in. (If any). Defaults to “1”
> - dragRestriction: Is the widget draggable? You can use this to prohibit the dragging of a specific Widget

This means you could use the following to get the column:

```js
myPortlet.get("column");
```

---

### Row

There is no such thing as a "row", so I suppose you want to retrieve the zone. There's no way to retrieve the zone of the portlet though, but you can calculate it by yourself. If you use `getChildren()` on the `GridContainer`, the portlets are always returned in the same order based on their column and then their zone. However, this is undocumented and may change in the future.

So this means you could easily write a counter that increments each time a portlet is in the same column (which means he's in the next zone). For example:

```js
var children = registry.byId("myGrid").getChildren();
var perColumn = [ ];
arrUtils.forEach(children, function(portlet) {
    var id = portlet.get("id");
    var col = portlet.get("column");
    if (perColumn[col] !== undefined) {
        perColumn[col]++;
    } else {
        perColumn[col] = 0;
    }
    var zn = perColumn[col];
    console.log(id + ": " + col + " " + zn);
});
```

### Get width + height of portlet

The width and the height of the portlet are determined by its content, so no `width` or `height` properties are available. However, you could get the DOM node of the content and retrieve the `width` and `height` from it using `dojo.position` (in recent versions it's the `dojo/dom-geom` module), for example:

```js
require([ "dojo/dom-geom" ], function(domGeom) {
    var box = domGeom.position(myPortlet.get("domNode"));
    console.log(box.w + " " + box.h);
});
```

I also made an example to retrieve all properties (column + zone + width + height): http://jsfiddle.net/dF94F/

Comment: If I applied to problem, i will be able to solve this problem. Thank you for always. Still lacks a lot of skills to solve the problem Every time. you give me a good answer. I have grateful to you every day.

Comment: Additional questions.if portlet has a splitter attribute,   can i control the width of the portlet itself?

Comment: Splitter attribute? Doesn't look like `dojox/widget/Portlet` supports that, according to the API docs: http://dojotoolkit.org/api/?qs=1.9/dojox/widget/Portlet

Comment: ok..hmm..can i adjust the width of the portlet functionality?